# Functional testing automation using javascript tools

Tags: node.js, jasmine, mocha.js, ui-automation, intern

I was looking for easily adoptable functional test (e2e) automation tools using javascript. I did some exploration and picked some (Mocha, Jasmine, nightwatch, and intern). It is mentioned commonly that Mocha, and Jasmine are used for unit test automation, and nightwatch/intern can be used for functional test automation (e2e).

I really don't understand the difference between these tools or what makes them to be categorized under functional or unit test tools? Can't Mocha or Jasmine be used for functional test automation?

Added to that, http://theintern.io/ compares the market leading javascript tools feature wise. "includes functional testing" feature is applicable only for intern and nightwatch. I need clarification that why the same cannot be done in Mocha/Jasmine. Need your expertise answers.

thanks
mani

Answer (score 0):

Mocha and Jasmine are purely unit testing frameworks. They don’t come with any code that could be used for performing functional testing. You could cobble together something yourself, using Mocha or Jasmine as the basis for writing tests and then adding some additional WebDriver client library like [Leadfoot](https://github.com/theintern/leadfoot), but you’d still need to figure out how to start and stop browsers, how to also run unit tests against your code in each of the browsers, how to run tests in parallel so it isn’t horribly slow (Mocha and Jasmine are both designed to only ever run one test at once), how to hook up to a cloud hosting provider using their software tunnels (if you want), and write and maintain all of that glue code yourself. Oh, and you lose all the other features that come with Intern, like integrated code coverage analysis, source map support, etc.

Intern provides all of this out of the box, and was actually designed with this sort of testing in mind, which means it will always work better than any solution you try to create yourself using some other library that wasn’t designed for the task at hand. This question is a lot like asking, “can’t I just write my own testing framework from scratch using plain JavaScript?”. Sure, you can do everything in plain JS. It doesn’t mean it’s a good idea, though.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Sorry, I am asking the same question again. Do you say that Mocha/Jasmine don't make use of selenium webdriver clients to do unit test? If not, how Intern/nightwatch.js differs from them and controlling the webdriver client. or you mean that there are no syntactic  sugar given by Mocha/Jasmine on top of webdriver to ease the pain of controlling the browsers, and parallel execution?

Comment: Mocha and Jasmine don’t have anything to do with WebDriver. They don’t drive browsers at all. They’re just very basic JavaScript unit testing libraries.